# How sensible is it to use latexmk?

Tags: latexmk

Until recently I always compiled my documents via the steps, `pdflatex -> makeindex/biber -> pdflatex -> pdflatex` (and the intermediate steps only if necessary).

`Latexmk` does all the necessary steps in one command for me but I suspect that comes with a drawback, what is it? One I can think of is that it maybe runs unnecessary steps and so it is a bit slower or is that not even true?
Are there drawbacks for using `latexmk`?

Comment: I don't think there are any drawbacks from using `latexmk`.  What you have to do is configure it before use.  You can either do that using a global `latexmkrc` or a local one in your project's folder.  If you think that `latexmk`might run unnecessary comilation, then you might want to have a look at [arara](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/support/arara/arara-usermanual.pdf), which gives you full control over all steps done.  Its successor `nightingale` will even support conditional execution of those steps.

Comment: i can think of only one drawback, and it's rather specialized.  sometimes it's necessary to look at or save an "interim" version of a `.toc` or `.aux` file, and `latexmk` would automatically wipe those out.  so the only way to avoid that is to perform the process step by step.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. That's something I can live with :)

Answer (score 158, accepted):

(As the author of `latexmk`, I am naturally partial to my own program, but here's my 2-cents' worth anyway.)

The fundamental problem that `latexmk` solves is that the number of runs of `(pdf)latex` needed is highly dynamically dependent on the document and the class file used.  If you make a small change to a document, often only one recompilation by `(pdf)latex` is needed, but not always.  But some cases consistently need at least 4 runs.  So running a fixed sequence of programs is definitely non-optimal.  `Latexmk` is designed to perform the right number of runs of the programs involved as reliably as possible while only using a small amount of resources compared with the called programs; most of the running time goes to `(pdf)latex` under normal situations.

The method it uses is to determine the set of all input files and to efficiently test for changes in content since the last run.  If the content of an input file has changed, a new compilation is made. For normal documents, this process works correctly.

One other advantage of `latexmk` is that if your document includes graphics files that need to be converted from the native form for the graphics editor (e.g., xfig), then `latexmk` can be configured do an automatic conversion to the format needed for `(pdf)latex`, e.g., .pdf or .eps.  For a human, it's one more mechanical step that's easy to forget occasionally, especially in documents with tens or hundreds of graphical elements.

The only regular case I know where `latexmk` consistently does an extra run, is that in the case mentioned by the OP, `latexmk` does an extra run of `bibtex` between the second and third runs of `pdflatex`.  It does this because the .aux file changed after the second run of `pdflatex`, and `latexmk` does not know that the particular changes that occurred do not actually matter to `bibtex`'s output.  The extra time for the `bibtex` run is small enough that it hasn't seemed worthwhile to do extra testing to optimize it.

As for when `latexmk` fails do enough runs, the cases I know of are when compilation of a document runs external programs or `luatex` code to process external files.  In these cases, `latexmk` doesn't normally know about the external files because the file names aren't reported by the running compilation, although that can be fixed.  However, for most people creating LaTeX documents this situation doesn't occur.